# Swift - Use of undeclared type 'Error'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Should not `Error` be a build in type? This:

```
import Foundation

struct Video {

  struct Source {

    enum SourceError: Error {
      case InvalidData
      case InvalidHeight
      case InvalidURL
    }
  }
}
```

gives me `Use of undeclared type 'Error'`.. I'm on xcode 8 beta 5

Comment: Compiles fine for me – try cleaning your build folder

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Hamish, Doesn't compile for me in Xcode 7.2.1.  Same error as op.

Comment: @EricAya The Xcode tag is not off topic, it's actually where the solution lied since the issue was not coming from swift but from corrupted build folder.